# Configuration for httphandler in classic mode

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, asp.net, 64-bit

I have to install an httphandler that needs to run on classic mode. I have created an application on the iis that uses a classic apppool and put the handler assembly there.

The vendor gave me a configuration in the deployment document that looks like this:

```
<system.web>
   <globalization requestEncoding="iso-8859-1" responseEncoding="iso-8859-1" />
   <httpModules>
   </httpModules>

   <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*" type="ProductName.ProductName, ProductName" />
   </httpHandlers>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
   <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

   <handlers>
      <add name="someUnspecificName" path="*" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />
   </handlers>

</system.webServer>
```

The error I get when requesting a URL on the application is a 404, so I guess the handle is not used at all.

Does the configuration look ok for a 64bit system?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that in

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*" type="ProductName.ProductName, ProductName" />
</httpHandlers>
```

your vendor told you to use `path="*"`?

The path attribute of a httphandler specifies the path or wildcard specification of the URL for which this handler will be invoked.

For example, if you want your handler to be called only when `dummy.abc` file is requested, the path attribute will contain "dummy.abc"; similarly if you want your handler called for any file having .abc extension, the path attribute will contain "*.abc".

---

**EDIT**

This article could be helpful: [Request Restrictions Dialog Box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742395.aspx).

> Use the Request Restrictions dialog
>   box to specify optional restrictions,
>   such as the requested resource type or
>   HTTP verb, for which you want a
>   handler to process requests. Configure
>   restrictions only if you have a
>   specific need to limit the conditions
>   under which a handler processes
>   requests. When you do not configure
>   restrictions, handlers will process
>   requests regardless of the resource
>   type requested and the HTTP verbs
>   specified.

I think that you'll have to disable restrictions of the existing default handlers ("Invoke handler only if request is mapped to").

Comment: Yes they need the wildcard. The Handler gets invoked on all request.